# Can I ask Git what is the directory of the local repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to write a gradle script that references the local git repository on all the user (development) machines.  I have it working with my hardcoded local directory name.  However, all the developers put their local repositories in a place of their own liking - this often varies between the Windows and Mac developers too!

Since I am in Groovy in the gradle script it would be simple for me to execute a local git command to get the directory where the local repository is stored.  Is there such an command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.

Comment: TOTALLY sweet!  Thank you - I looked quite a bit before posting and could not easily find this anywhere.  I can accept your answer in five more minutes - so you were fast too!